# How to check if a pointer still points to valid memory in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer which equals to another pointer

I'd like to check if my pointer equals to a pointer which is not null.

```
int* ptr0 = new int(5);
int* ptr1 = ptr0;

delete ptr0;

if ( ?? )
{
    std::cout << "ptr1 equals to a null ptr" << std::endl;
}
```

What should I write in the condition ?

Knowing that:

- I **don't want to set nullptr** any of the ptr's after removal
- I **don't have access** to ptr0 in my condition

Comment: You can't. You need a smart pointer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0xDEADBEEF#Magic_debug_values Some compilers will overwrite the memory of the delete pointer with `magic numbers`. It isn't done just in debugging alone. But in some releases as well. You can check for that and see if memory was deleted.. MSVC does this.. Apple's is: `A bad babe` lol..

Comment: magic numbers do not work, sorry.  But if you allocate the same block of memory then you cant rely on this, and shouldn't.  C++ allows you to set a pointer to any value you want and it is still a valid pointer, even though the data pointed to is not valid.  This is not something any compiler grants you.  Smart pointers only work when managed by the owner of the memory that has been allocated, and deleted without your knowledge.  If its not set up to provide you with a safe access mechanism then there is nothing you can do later to garantee that it is safe.

Comment: The idea is to fix your code so it can't happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`shared_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) combined with a [`weak_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).

For example,

```
int main() {
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> ptr0(new int);
    std::tr1::weak_ptr<int> ptr1_weak(ptr0);

    *ptr0 = 50;

    // Depending on if you reset or not the code below will execute
    //ptr0.reset();

    if (std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> ptr1 = ptr1_weak.lock()) {
        std::cout << "Changing value!" << std::endl;
        *ptr1 = 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you can elaborate your answer a bit as the OP is likely not familiar with shared/weak_ptr and their usage pattern. :)

Comment: I just added a code sample illustrating the concept. These two smart pointers are both available in C++98 via Boost libraries and in C++11 via `<memory>`.

Comment: Awesome, this is as neat & concise as you can get w/ 98. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. While in theory you could, depending on the implementation of `new`, check if the memory pointed to is currently in use there's no way to confirm that it's still the same object you were originally pointing to using only raw pointers.

You can use C++11 smart pointers to do something kinda like that, but I really don't think that's what you actually wanna do here.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` does not result in a null pointer. It results in a dangling pointer, which is undetectable in general. So, you cannot.